# mongoose find returned undefined document

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have some code that looks like this. Literally only cosmetic changes 
& removals made from my actual code:

```
Entry.find(conditions)
.select('ymd intentions outcomes goalCounts')
.lean()
.exec()
.then(function (entries) {
  if (!entries.length) {
    res.write(']')
    res.end()
  }
  entries[entries.length-1].isLast = true
  // more processing of entries etc
}, function (err) {
  // do something with error
})
```

It usually works, but my production server just reported an error: that the `isLast=true` line failed with

`TypeError: Cannot set property 'isLast' of undefined`

Since there's a check right there that ensures the array itself isn't empty, I know that what was passed into this function was a non-empty array whose last item was itself undefined. `ymd` is a required field, so there shouldn't be any results that would be `{}`.

Is this expected behavior under any condition (something to do with `lean()`?) or does it represent some sort of mongo bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code continues after the `if` check you mention, so if `entries` has 0 length, you'll get the error you're seeing.

Ether return after the `res.end()` call, or put the line that's throwing the error in an `else` clause:

```
if (!entries.length) {
  res.write(']')
  res.end()
  return;
}
entries[entries.length-1].isLast = true
```

OR

```
if (!entries.length) {
  res.write(']')
  res.end()
} else {
  entries[entries.length-1].isLast = true
}
```

Comment: Ha. Of course. Seeing "res.end()" made me think it was done. Duh! I know better than this.